# How to pass value from one component to another using onClick in React

Tags: reactjs

Currently having a list of items and i want to show data about a particular item when that item is clicked, I tried by creating a button that will pass that item's id to another Component, but it's not working

render code :-

```
return(

    <div className="mainn">
    <div>
      <h4>Toilet Search:</h4>
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.searchHandler}/>
      </form>
      <h3>List of Toilets</h3>
      <table  className="gfg">
        <tr className="head">
          <th>Toilet ID  </th>
          <th>Toilet's Location  </th>
          <th>GeoLocation</th>
        </tr>
        {toilet.filter(searchingFor(this.state.term)).map(developer => (
            <div
              key={developer.uid}
              className="card"        
            >      
                <tr>
                <td className="tid">{developer.tid}</td>  
                <td className="loc" onClick={<Graph />}>{developer.location}</td>
                <button onClick={<Graph tid={developer.tid}/>}>Data</button>
                <td>{developer.geoLoc}</td>
                </tr>

           </div>
            ))}
      </table>               
          </div>
    </div>      
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? Also, please post your `Graph` component.

Answer (score 1):

you canNot render component onClick of onother component
you should set the item that you want to show in state, then pass it to that component using

change this line

```
<button onClick={<Graph tid={developer.tid}/>}>Data</button>
```

to

```
<button
    onClick={() => this.setState({
        selectedDeveloperId:developer.tid
    })}
>
    Data
</button>
```

so now if you click on the button, it will set developer id in state of component

and in render method after closing tag of table put this

```
{!!selectedDeveloperId && (<Graph tid={selectedDeveloperId}/>)}
```

so it will render Grap component if you click on a button with id of selected developer

Comment: Thanks you for the answer but when i load the app it's saying 'selectedDeveloperId' is not defined, i did define it in the constructor's this.state object

Comment: yeah, you should add the selectedDeveloperId in the state with default value of null

`constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        // other states
        selectedDeveloperId: null,
    };
}`